# Check if a div has any children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below code that checks to see if any of my divs has the class "wrong" and if so it shows the jQuery UI dialog box. However i want to extend the code so that it checks those divs and if there are any that are empty it should not show the dialog box.

I've looked around and some people are suggesting using children().length > 0 to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how to write this with my code.

js:

```
$("#run").click(function() {
  if ($("[id^='Drop']").hasClass("wrong")) {
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "divs are empty" ? They have no content?

Comment: You can use [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector which select elements without children

Comment: Just clarify, the dialog should only be displayed when there is at least 1 div with the `wrong` class and 0 of those divs are empty, correct?  The answers below don't seem to be using that logic.

Comment: @adamdc78 I've actually read it that way, but after reviewing my answer I started to doubt the practical purposes of such a condition ... :)

Comment: @adamdc78 you're right  that is what i want to happen

Answer (score 4):

The following selectors could be used to test if an element is empty or not:

- [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) matches elements that have no children (thus, empty)<sup>+</sup>
- [`:parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) matches elements that have children<sup>+</sup>

Now, rephrasing your statement:

> ... so that it checks <del>those</del> wrong divs and if
>   <del>there are any that are empty</del> they are all full it should
>   <del>not</del> show the dialog box.

You would write:

```
var $allWrong = $("id[^='Drop'].wrong"),
    $notEmpty = $wrong.filter(":parent");
if ($allWrong.length && $allWrong === $notEmpty) {
    // show dialog
}
```

---

<sup><sup>+</sup> Text nodes are counted when counting children. `<span> </span>` contains a text node which contains a whitespace. Therefore it matches `:parent` and does not match `:empty`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The logic consists of two parts:

1. Finding elements with `id` property starting with `"Drop"` and having the `.wrong` class.
2. Checking whether any of those elements are empty.

To do this, I'm saving the first step in an intermediate variable, before doing the final condition:

```
var $wrongFields = $('[id^="Drop"].wrong');

if ($wrongFields.length && !$wrongFields.filter(':empty').length) {
    // at least one field exists with:
    // - id starting with "Drop"
    // - class of "wrong"
    // and none of those fields are empty
    $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/xurexolici/1/)

Comment: the dialog box does not appear when i try using this code

Comment: but yes..what you have written is exactly what I'm trying to implement

Comment: @TryingAtCode perhaps you could provide a fiddle like in my answer where it doesn't work; that way it's easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

This would also work

```
$("#run").click(function(){
    if ($("[id^='Drop']").hasClass("wrong") && $("[id^='Drop'].wrong:empty").length ) {
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
});
```